# How to define JSON in route and pass JSON object to Web API 2 as parameter or equivalent

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core-2.0

I have Angular application that is consuming .NET CORE 2.0 Web API, I need to ensure route define strongly type of class 'ResponseCurrentStateDataView' and receive JSON object as parameter from Angular application

### Angular Class structure

```
export class ResponseCurrentStateDataModel
{
  consultationId:string;
  responseTypeId: string;
  responseTypeTitle:string;
  responsesRequestedStatus:string;
}
```

### C# class structure

```
public class ResponseCurrentStateDataView
{
    public Guid ConsultationId { get; set; }
    public Guid ResponseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ResponseTypeTitle { get; set; }
    public string ResponsesRequestedStatus { get; set; }
}
```

### Web API (how to define route structure and parameter??? )

```
    [Route("[action]/{responseCurrentStateObject}")]   // i believe this is incorrect
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetResponsesByResponseStatusType(ResponseCurrentStateDataView responseCurrentStateObj)  ??????
    {
        //my code.... responseList
        return Json(responsesList);

    }
```

Comment: if you want to pass an object or JSON to an web api call, use POST or PUT method. GET accepts only an ID and returns the object. [FromBody] is used to get the JSON body passed from UI to API call

Answer (score 1):

So you really shouldn't be passing json text though a GET request. If you try using a POST you can do it like so:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public TestObjectFromNg Post([FromBody] TestObjectFromNg value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class TestObjectFromNg
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also notice I typed the return value and I simply returned the typed value with out calling Json(). Web Api 2 will convert the object to json automagically.